# React.js - array not displaying correctly after getting strings from textfile

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, iterator, fetch-api

I'm working on a program in React.js, and I'm having trouble getting of the arrays to display correctly. I've tried various "join" statements, none of which seem to do the trick. I've tried splitting the lines by using split(/\r?\n/).
I'm using the Fetch API to call a text file and then put the contents into an array, which I then want to display to the screen. If anyone can give any pointers as to why it might not be working, please point them out!

Here's my code:

cats.txt

```
Persian
Himalayan
Siamese
Sphynx
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "Cat" from "./components/Cat.js";
import catFile from "cats.txt";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
      cat_Array: []
    }
    getCats = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
        fetch(catFile).then(data => data.text()),
        .then(allResponses => {
          let catArray = allResponses.split(/\r?\n/);
this.setState({
                    cat_array: catArray
                  })
            }
          }
        })
      }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <h2> Cats</h2>
      <Cats
        getCats={this.getCats}
        />

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

components/Cat.js

```
import React from 'react';

class Cat extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               <p> {this.props.getCats} </p>
            </div>)
    }
}

export default Cat;
```

Actual Output

```
PersianHimalayanSiameseSphynx
```

Expected Output

```
Persian
Himalayan
Siamese
Sphynx
```

Comment: You just dump out an array of cats. Perhaps you should iterate and put each in a div or in a list etc.

Answer (score 1):

I added a few lines code and got your desired output. Change the followings -

Replace the body of `fetch` with this -

```
  fetch(catFile)
    .then(data => data.text())
    .then(allResponses => {
      let catArray = allResponses.split('\n');
      this.setState({
           cat_Array: catArray
       });
   });
```

Add this code in the `render()` method -

```
const catData = this.state.cat_Array.map((data) => {
      return (
        <span>{data} <br/></span>
      )
    });
```

Now pass the `castData` as props in the Cat component instead of calling `this.props.getCats`. So now you can directly show the data like this - `{catData}`

Hope you got the idea.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! If the question solved the problem you can mark it as accepted. Will be helpful for others